# Integrate Nodejs and Python using rabbitmq

Tags: python, node.js, rabbitmq, nameko

I have 3 microservices built using python, rabbitmq and nameko. I have 1 nodejs service which I want to register onto rabbitmq. I want the python service to communicate with the nodejs service over rabbitmq rpc. I searched numerous links on web, but could not find any useful reference. I would prefer if python to node communication could happen using nameko. Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

https://www.npmjs.com/package/miko is a NodeJS client for Nameko's RPC protocol.

You may also want to consider using gRPC rather than the AMQP RPC implementation that Nameko ships with. There's a great writeup and example project doing this here: https://itnext.io/grpc-apis-with-nameko-11bbd9492225